# Getter and Setter are not created for Amplify Model

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I followed the Amplify for Flutter, after I run amplify pull sandboxId I got this error in the class that it created, please help[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement missing property with empty list, if there is no custom schemas.

```
  @override
  List<ModelSchema> customTypeSchemas = [];
```

Comment: I got this error after running the code : "W/Parcel  ( 6080): Expecting binder but got null!" Is it something I need to worry about